# The image do not fit the parent div

Tags: html, css

i have html like this:

```
<section class="parent>
<div class="first-child"> 
<form>
</form>
</div>
<div class="second-child">
<img/>
</div>
</section>
```

and the css:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
.first-child {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.second-child {
position: absolute;
  flex: 0 0 70%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.second-child img {
 display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

i want the each div has 50% of parent width, and "the 20% of second div" will hidden under the first one. I try to make second child with position: absolute and left: 30%. But it's still not working, the image in second div is exceeding it.
So how can i make that with css. Thank in advance

i try several ways but still not working.

Comment: Your code does not produce anything sensible, see: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/MWLoaLm There's clearly no image in `<img/>`. We cannot work with pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of effect you want? I’ve used a grid to manage the layout.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr 3fr 2fr;
}

.first-child {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.second-child {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <div class="first-child"></div>
  <div class="second-child"></div>
</section>
```